# how to add a link to jframe in java netbeans projects

Tags: java, swing

Hey guys I want to add a link to a button on my JFrame using netbeans.

In JAVA projects I have created a Facebook button but I want it when the user clicks he or she is directed to Facebook.

Comment: @martin  i really just want to include a link on my facebook button in Jframe forms..thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can try this with [`java.awt.Desktop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html),

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent){
  try {                
         Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI.create("http://www.example.com"));
      }catch(IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Comment: wooow lemmy give it a try ...i have a project am working on if it works i will pay you 100$ thru paypal

Comment: hey @Andrew Thompson am getting an  error" cannot find  symbol variable Desktop and class tenant edit"

Comment: @SinaJina hit `[ctrl]+[shift]+[i]` to resolve imports

Comment: hey please can someone please send me code on the comments ..n@peeskillet the neccessary imports coz i have imported but to no avail